# Angular Kendo Grid Unit tests, Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

You have Kendo Angular components, you are running the unit tests and you get an error with the code below.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
```

It works but the unit test doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec.ts file needs an import

```
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [KendoGridExampleComponent],
        imports: [GridModule]
```

You can copy the import path from the app.module.ts file